# Repeated roots of $\det(A-xI)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank

The solutions of the equation $\det(A-xI)=0$ give rise to the eigenvalues of Matrix $A$. This confuses me because the equation can give repeated roots. Suppose there is a root $x=\lambda$ of multiplicity $n$, and the corresponding eigenvectors are $\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$. Then any linear combination of these vectors is an eigenvector, because $A(v_1+v_2)=Av_1+Av_2=\lambda v_1+\lambda v_2=\lambda(v_1+v_2)$ .

What I find puzzling is that those $n$ vectors doesn't have to be linear independent. For example, the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\-4&1\end {bmatrix}$  has a repeated eigenvalue $\lambda=1$ of multiplicity 2, but the corresponding vector space of eigenvectors is only one dimensional, spanned by $(0,1)^T$. This lead me to the following questions.

> If a non-singular matrix $A$ satisfies $\operatorname{rank}(A-\lambda I)=\operatorname{rank}(A)-n$, does the equation $\det(A-xI)=0$ always have a repeated root of multiplicity greater than or equal to $n$ at $x=\lambda$?
>
> Under what conditions are those $\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$ above linearly independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a full answer. It's just a collection of thoughts related to your predicament. It is, however, a bit long for a comment.

What you have here is an example of an eigenvalue whose *geometric multiplicity* (the dimension of the corresponding eigenspace) is strictly smaller than the *algebraic multiplicity* (the degree of the root of the characteristic polynomial).

One concept invented to resolve this is *generalized eigenvectors*, which are vectors $v$ where $(A-\lambda I)v$ isn't necessarily $0$, but $(A-\lambda I)^nv=0$ for some natural number $n$. And you can always find enough generalized eigenvectors for a given eigenvalue to make up for the discrepancy you noted here. In your case, any vector in the plane is a generalized eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$, which suits the degree of the root $\lambda=1$ in your characteristic polynomial.

If all the eigenvalues does have the "correct" dimension of all its eigenspaces, then the matrix and the linear transformation it represents is *diagonalizable*. If there is some eigenspace which is "too small", then it is not diagonalizable. The resolution here, related to the concept of generalized eigenvectors above, is the so-called *Jordan normal form*, which says that when transforming $A$ to some specific basis of generalized eigenvectors, the resulting matrix is almost diagonal. It will have the eigenvalues in the diagonal, and $1$'s in some places along the superdiagonal (and otherwise $0$).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to think about this might be the eigenspaces, not eigenvectors. If you have a nondegenerate eigenvalue (i.e. $n=1$), the space of eigenvectors is $1$-dimensional and thus you can determine it by giving a single nonzero vector $v_1$, which automatically yields a basis $\{v_1\}$.

If you have $n > 1$ though, what you mean by $\{v_1, ..., v_n\}$ is some basis of the eigenspace, and that's just where the linear independence comes from. As a basis, the $v_i$ are in no way uniquely determined though. I think that's where your confusion comes from.

Comment: The way I read the question, this isn't about the non-uniqueness (up to scaling) of an eigenbasis, but about how there are "missing" dimensions of the eigenspace compared to the multiplicity of roots in the characteristic polynomial.